# Bash: find and copy exec command not recursive

Tags: bash, recursion

I'm running this command to `find all` the files named **deploy.php** in my whole project and make a copy of them and place them in the same directory as they were found, with name **deploy_bkp.php**

```
find . -type f -name "deploy.php" -exec cp  {} deploy_bkp.php  \;
```

But its not working recursively. its only working for files on the top directory.

Can anyone help me. thank u

Comment: Instead of calling `cp '{}' ...` directly, you will want to create a small helper script (e.g. `cp "$1" "$2"` in the helper, call it `mycp`) then you can use `find . -type f -name "deploy.php" -exec mycp '{}' -printf "%h/deploy_bkp.php";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`. With `-exec`, the current directory doesn't change for each file, so the backup file is created in your starting directory, regardless of where `deploy.php` is found. `-execdir` tells find to chdir to the correct directory beforehand, so your `cp` will behave as expected.